# Why is this thread affecting the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I must be missing something:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Thread(new Action())).run();
        System.out.println("Blah");
    }
}

class Action implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

        }
    }
}
```

I make a thread that is supposed to be running a loop.

In my main thread I print "Blah".

However, it is never printed. Why not? If I made a separate thread, it shouldn't affect my main execution thread, right?

This machine has four cores.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call `start()` instead of `run()` to start a thread.

Simply calling `run()` means a method call with infinite loop in the same `main` thread that will block the next statement written in `main` thread.

Have a look at [Java Tutorial on Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

---

I should be `(new Thread(new Action())).start();` to start a thread but still it will create an infinite loop and the new started thread will never stop.

Try with `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to **confirm** it again as shown below:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // output "main"
}
```

#### A Pictorial Representation of Thread Life-cycle along with it's methods

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Because you are not invoking `start()`, you are calling directly the implementation method of the thread `run()`, thus no thread is started, code is just executed.

`run()` is the method called by the thread internal structure to execute the task, since it's just a normal method which doesn't have anything attached.